# Why mpi wait long time when oob connect to peer?

Tags: networking, mpi, openmpi, hpc

**Topology of my cluster**

I have a cluster with 4 server (named A, B, C, D), each of which has a network card with 4 ports.
4 server are connected to each other directly as full mesh topology. Then 3 ports of each server is occupied.

The last unused port of each server is connected to a switch as a star topology.

At last, A can communicates with B though the switch or directly connection.

**How I run my MPI**

I run wrf4.2.1 with OpenMPI4.0.1 under RoCE protocol. I just use 2 node(A and B).

`mpirun  --allow-run-as-root --mca oob_base_verbose 100  --hostfile $host_file -x OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 -map-by ppr:64:node:pe=4 -np $process_num  --report-bindings --bind-to core -x OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 -x OMP_WAIT_POLICY=active -x OMP_DISPLAY_ENV=true -x OMP_DISPLAY_AFFINITY=true -x OMP_PLACES=cores -x OMP_PROC_BIND=close -x OMP_SCHEDULE=static -x OMP_STACKSIZE=1G -mca pml ucx -mca btl ^uct,openib -x UCX_TLS=self,sm,rc -x UCX_NET_DEVICES=hrn0_0:1,hrn0_1:1,hrn0_2:1,hrn0_3:1,hrn0_5:1,hrn0_6:1,hrn0_7:1 -x UCX_IB_GID_INDEX=3 --mca io romio321 ./wrf.exe`

**The phenomenon**

When I run the command on server A. It works correctly and I can see processes named wrf very soon.

When I run the command on server B. I wait long time(minutes) for wrf process to start.(If I choose C and D, it works on one server and delays for long before start on another as well)

**Logs for debugging**

I can see something from oob log but hard to understand.

When there is delay, I can see

```
[localhost.localdomain:62939] [[27400,0],1] set_peer: peer [[27400,0],0] is listening on net xxx1 port 40139
[localhost.localdomain:62939] [[27400,0],1] set_peer: peer [[27400,0],0] is listening on net xxx2 port 40139
[localhost.localdomain:62939] [[27400,0],1] set_peer: peer [[27400,0],0] is listening on net xxx3 port 40139
[localhost.localdomain:62939] [[27400,0],1] set_peer: peer [[27400,0],0] is listening on net xxx4 port 40139
```

Here xxx1 to xxx4 are ip of ports of server B. oob start tcp listening on all ports.

Then it will wait for long time at

```
[localhost.localdomain:62939] [[27400,0],1] orte_tcp_peer_try_connect: attempting to connect to proc [[27400,0],0]
[localhost.localdomain:62939] [[27400,0],1] orte_tcp_peer_try_connect: attempting to connect to proc [[27400,0],0] on socket -1
[localhost.localdomain:62939] [[27400,0],1] orte_tcp_peer_try_connect: attempting to connect to proc [[27400,0],0] on xxx1:40139 - 0 retries
[localhost.localdomain:62939] [[27400,0],1] waiting for connect completion to [[27400,0],0] - activating send event
```

It tries all the ports until the port though which server B is connected with server A. At each port it wait for minutes at `activating send event`.

**What I tried**

If I delete all network device except the one connects to switch, mpi works well on both server A and B.

**The question**

1. Why oob wait for so long at `activating send event`? What does it do here?
2. Why mpi_run works well on 1 server but not on another? How could I debug this problem?

Comment: Try restricting oob traffic to the interface known to work. For example, `mpirun --mca oob_tcp_if_include eth0 ...`

Comment: It works! The key is to indicate the port to use for oob communication.